# Percentage + max-width style container with overlapping block on right side

Tags: html, css, responsive

So I want to create a layout design like this below.

https://cln.sh/SSzT0Z

I can get it to work at most screen sizes by having the following styles, but when the max-width comes into play it breaks and leaves a gap

> HTML

```
<div="overlapping-container">
  <div="overlapping-container__block"></div>
  <div="main-container">Some other divs/content goes here for middle section</div>
  <div="overlapping-container__block--white-bg"></div>
</div>
```

> CSS

```
.overlapping-container { 
  margin-top: -200px; /* To make it overlap into previous section */
  display: flex;
}

.overlapping-container__block {
  width: 15%;
}

.main-container {
  width:85%;
  max-width: 1350px; /* As it gets way to wide on certain screen sizes, but this is what breaks the overlap at certain sizes */
}
```

Heres what my current solution looks like (as you can see there is a gap on a very wide screen because of the max-width

https://cln.sh/R5BrAP

I've also tried adding a min-width: 15%; to the overlapping-container__block with a width of 1000px or whatever but still no luck that just creates other issues.

I'd like to continue to use flexbox if possible. Any ideas how I can make this work with no gap but still keeping my max-width on the middle section?

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid overlapping content if it is only about a background, you may dispatch backgrounds into the parent and the child.

`Calc()` can come to rescue you to set your `max-width` via recalculating padding .

example :

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.body {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #00464F 200px, transparent 200px) #bee;
  padding: 2em calc( (100% - 1350px) / 2);/* will turn to null  if result becomes negative */
  min-height: 100vh;/optional*/
}

h1 {
  color: white;
  text-shadow:0 0 1px black;
}

main {/* whatever, to give some content here for the demo */
  padding: 1em;
  column-count: 2;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class='body'>
  <header>
    <h1>header</h1>
  </header>
  <main>

    <h1>HTML Ipsum Presents</h1>

    <p><strong>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</strong> senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. <em>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</em>      Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, <code>commodo vitae</code>, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci,
      sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. <a href="#">Donec non enim</a> in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.</p>

    <h2>Header Level 2</h2>

    <ol>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
      <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
    </ol>

    <blockquote>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus magna. Cras in mi at felis aliquet congue. Ut a est eget ligula molestie gravida. Curabitur massa. Donec eleifend, libero at sagittis mollis, tellus est malesuada tellus, at luctus
        turpis elit sit amet quam. Vivamus pretium ornare est.</p>
    </blockquote>

    <h3>Header Level 3</h3>

    <ul>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
      <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
    </ul>

    <pre><code>
#header h1 a {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 80px;
}
</code></pre>
  </main>



</div>
```

You can also use a [custom CSS `var()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/var()) to easily reuse or reset that bit of code, example reset at 500px that you can easily update from `--Layout-Max-Width : 500px;` :

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html {
--Layout-Max-Width : 500px;
}

.body {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #00464F 200px, transparent 200px) #bee;
  padding: 2em calc( (100% - var(--Layout-Max-Width)) / 2);/* will turn to null  if result becomes negative */
  min-height: 100vh;/optional*/
}

h1 {
  color: white;
  text-shadow:0 0 2px #00464F
}

main {/* whatever, to give some content here for the demo */
  padding: 1em;
  column-count: 2;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class='body'>
  <header>
    <h1>header</h1>
  </header>
  <main>

    <h1>HTML Ipsum Presents</h1>

    <p><strong>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</strong> senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. <em>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</em>      Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, <code>commodo vitae</code>, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci,
      sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. <a href="#">Donec non enim</a> in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.</p>

    <h2>Header Level 2</h2>

    <ol>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
      <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
    </ol>

    <blockquote>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus magna. Cras in mi at felis aliquet congue. Ut a est eget ligula molestie gravida. Curabitur massa. Donec eleifend, libero at sagittis mollis, tellus est malesuada tellus, at luctus
        turpis elit sit amet quam. Vivamus pretium ornare est.</p>
    </blockquote>

    <h3>Header Level 3</h3>

    <ul>
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
      <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
    </ul>

    <pre><code>
#header h1 a {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 80px;
}
</code></pre>
  </main>



</div>
```

here is a codepen to play with (grid used)  : https://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/zYKPXez

Comment: Sorry thanks for the help on this. But i'm confused how it solves the issue. 


I've made another image to illustrate what I'm trying to do 

https://cln.sh/ZB350k

Comment: @Sam you mean sent to the right side ? https://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/wvzPLKe

Comment: Hey no so I mean as shown in the screenshot 
https://cln.sh/ZB350k

Left block of 15% on the left (stretches past 15% if the middle block is capped at the max width 1350px)

Middle block of 85% (max-width: 1350px)

Right block of 15% (larger than 15% if the max-width has capped the middle block.

Comment: @Sam okay, you could also manage a grid-template. however, the idea is to overlapp backgrounds, not elements ;) that was the main point / main tip of my answer. https://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/QWKaWNa

Comment: Ah okay that was a part of the solution I already had down with the negative margin. But I've found the answer to my question anyways! (through working it out and added it above)

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I added an additional class ontop of .overlapping-container__block to the right block called .overlapping-container__block--white

Which I added the flex-grow attribute to and also the white bg.

This solved my problem!

Hope this answer helps someone else using flexbox for a similar challenge.